# NLTK Add Text to Dataset

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

I'm trying to add data to the NLTK dataset to make a machine learning project. However, I can't figure out how to add text to the NLTK dataset.

My code is as follows:

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
from nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet import WordNetCorpusReader

data_path = 'training.csv'

wn_reader = WordNetCorpusReader(nltk.data.find('corpora/wordnet'), None)

wn_reader.insert(data_path)

def get_wordnet_pos(word):
    """Map POS tag from treebank form to wordnet form"""
    tag_dict = {"J": wordnet.ADJ,
                "N": wordnet.NOUN,
                "V": wordnet.VERB,
                "R": wordnet.ADV}
    tag = nltk.pos_tag([word])[0][1][0].upper()
    return tag_dict.get(tag, wordnet.NOUN)

def correct_sentence(text):
    """Correct sentence grammar"""
    words = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
    # Using List Comprehension Instead of a for loop
    words_corrected = [wordnet.morphy(word, get_wordnet_pos(word)) or word for word, tag in nltk.pos_tag(words)]
    return ' '.join(words_corrected)

text = "I have writed a message but forgot to send it."
corrected_text = correct_sentence(text)
print(corrected_text)
```

I also don't know whether to use a csv file or not.

After getting the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
    wn_reader = WordNetCorpusReader(nltk.data.find('wordnet'), None)
  File "/home/runner/myfolder/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nltk/data.py", line 560, in find
    resource_zipname = resource_name.split("/")[1]
IndexError: list index out of range,
```

I tried to read the NLTK howto at [the NLTK website](https://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html), but sadly it was no help.